# extract data from contact form 7 email and inject into database using postie function

Tags: mysql, wordpress, contact-form-7

i’ve set up an online form using contact form 7 that posts to my secret postie email address. each email gets collected and listed in draft format for moderation.

the post_type i’m using is one called testimonials that comes with my theme, which doesn’t have a body section as such, instead it has four custom fields – ‘author_name’, ‘author_company’ [not required], ‘author_url’ [also not required] and ‘author_quote’.

what i would like to do is have postie auto-fill the author_name and author_quote fields instead of trying to fill the [non-existent] body, using the your-name and your-message fields in contact form 7. that is, i want the values of the contact form your-name and your-message fields to be injected into the database as the meta_values of the pyre_author_name and pyre_author_quote meta_keys

i hope that makes sense?

i tried tweaking the add_custom_field function in the filterPostie.php file to see if anything worked, but no

```
function add_custom_field($post) {
    if (‘testimonials’ == get_post_type()) {
        add_post_meta($post[‘ID’], ‘pyre_author_name’, ‘$your_name’);
        add_post_meta($post[‘ID’], ‘pyre_author_quote’, ‘your-message’);
        return $your_name;
        return your-message;
    }
}
```

can anyone see what i'm doing wrong, or know what i might have to try to achieve what i want?

the site i'm working on is here: https://sistascarpentry.co.uk/testimonials/

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://contactform7.com/setting-default-values-to-the-logged-in-user/

Comment: thanks but i need to extract the message as well as the name and inject it into the two pyre meta keys

Comment: In that case, create your own form tag.

Comment: you could be correct and i've looked at some of the examples at the contact form 7 website [which i have to admit fry my brains somewhat]. it occurs to me that any form tags created will need to be parsed by the postie plugin [presumably using its filterPostie.php file] and that parsing needs to target the theme's custom pyre_author_name and pyre_author_quote variables in the database.

Comment: why not map your form to the post_type directly instead via the email so a new post is created each time the form is submitted.

Comment: this is the function of the postie plugin, it creates a new post using the subject and body content of the email and it is precisely this that i want to map the post_types in. unfortunately i can't work out how!

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that you can use a plugin like [Post My CF7 Form](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-my-contact-form-7/) to save directly as a draft post in your back-end.  You can then insert the link to the dashboard post edit page in your email and access the draft post directly before deciding to publish it or scrap it.